# SQLite problems with Android 7.1 & Android 8.0 - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-8.0-oreo, sqlite-net

SQLite.Net.Standard is not working in Android 8 in Xamarin Forms. 
What is the alternative ?

I installed SQLIte.Net.Standard but found i was getting "Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: /system/lib/libsqlite.so occurred" at runtime.

Further reading indicated that starting with Android 7, access to this lib was removed or restricted. Supposedly the fix was using a different Nuget package.
SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroidN

Comment: What is not working? Adding more information is always suggested

Comment: I installed SQLIte.Net.Standard but found i was getting "Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: /system/lib/libsqlite.so occurred" at runtime.

Further reading indicated that starting with Android 7, access to this lib was removed or restricted. Supposedly the fix was using a different Nuget package.
SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroidN

Answer (score 1):

I use the alternative NuGet Package [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) from praeclarum with Android 8 + 9 devices and had no problems so far.

Usage:

```
var db = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(dbPath, dbFile));
db.CreateTable<YourModel>();
var yourObject = new YourModel();
db.Insert(yourObject);
```